# How can I request variables if using Async?

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask

I'm trying to ask for variables, but the usage of Async doesn't allow it and create error, How can I solve it?

```
class getComics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(String comicName, int getOptionNumber){ 

    private String comicName;
    private int getOptionNumber;
    String jsonString = "";
    String result = ""; 

    //set option for search
    public void SetOptionNumber(int optionNumber){  
        this.getOptionNumber = optionNumber;

    }

    public int GetOptionNumber(){
        return this.getOptionNumber;
    }

    //the data that the user searching for
    public void SetComicName(String incomingComicName){
        this.comicName = incomingComicName;     
    }

    public String GetComicName(){
        return this.comicName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make constructor of your `AsyncTask` like below:-

```
class getComics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){ 

  getComics(String comicName, int getOptionNumber)
  {
  }
  // do code of asynctask
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use argument Constructor to pass required values.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
class getComics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(String comicName, int getOptionNumber) {
...
}
```

You should modify as below

```
class getComics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
...
}
```

You can see document and example here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html